# Qt: what happens if you send out signals too quickly?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

Here is the situation:

- You have one long-running calculation running in a background thread.
- This calculation is sending out a signal to, for example, refresh a GUI element, every 100 msec.
- Let's say it sends out 100 such signals.
- The widget being redrawn takes more than 100 msec to redraw; let's say 1 second.

What happens in the event loop? Do the signal calls "pile up" until they are all executed (i.e. 100 seconds)? Is there any mechanism for "dropping" events?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

User events are never discarded. If you queue emitted signal events faster than you can process them, your event queue will grow until you run out of memory and your program will crash. It's worth noting, though, that QTimer will skip timeout events if the system is under heavy load. To some extent, that may help regulate your throughput.

You could also consider sending feedback from one thread to the other (an acknowledgement, perhaps), and manually adjust your timing in the producer thread based on how far behind the consumer thread is. Or, you could use a metaphorical sledgehammer and switch to a blocking queued connection.

Answer (score 3):

In your example, you could measure the drawing time in the widget. If the drawing takes for example 240 ms, then you could process the next 2 signals quickly without drawing anything at all. That way the signals wouldn't pile up.

**Edit:**

Actually there is a slight problem in my solution. The last signal should always cause a redraw, otherwise the widget would show wrong data when the calculation is finished.

When a signal is skipped, a single shot timer could be started for example with a 150 ms interval. When a redraw is done because of a signal, this timer would be stopped. So after the last redraw signal, this single shot timer would cause the drawing of the final state. I guess this would work, but it would be quite complicated.

Starting a simple timer to do the redrawing when the calculation starts would quite probably be a better approach. If the drawing of the widget takes a lot of time, the timer interval could be dynamically adjusted according to the draw time.

Comment: +1. I think I like this sort of solution more than anything I proposed. Though, you could go further and entirely decouple the frequency of the calculation from the frequency of the drawing. Just cache the last emitted value, and redraw based on a timer.

Comment: The best approach really depends on the case. Redrawing with QTimer would be simple and therefore a good solution, if the redrawing must be done constantly and the redrawing doesn't take too much time. But if the redraw is usually not needed at all and then sometimes there are bursts of changes that require the quite heavy redraw, then the solution I presented might be better.

Comment: I found a problem in my solution and added some more text to the answer.